# HDMI CEC Implementation in Linux

Tags: 14.04, hdmi, intel-nuc

Any Idea about Hdmi CEC application development in linux. I want to implement user space as well kernel space application. Any one have an idea please let me know how to implement

Comment: 14.04 is long past EOL and no longer gets support here.

Comment: Canonical, the maker of Ubuntu will continue to support 14.04 and 16.04 through Extended Security Maintenance until April 2024. Ask Ubuntu is currently trying to change policy to make 16.04 off topic here. ESM is free and not too hard to set up. I discus a little bit about activating it at this link: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19510/is-ubuntu-14-04-off-topic-on-ask-ubuntu/19529#19529 You can vote to continue Ask Ubuntu support for ESM versions of Ubuntu here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19543/policy-change-proposal-end-of-standard-support-for-esm-releases-is-effectivel

Comment: CEC is a hardware implementation. Not software. Laptops must use an inline dongle to send and receive CEC commands. Raspberry Pi have it included as part of its infrastructure. The linux kernel accepts cec: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/media/kapi/cec-core.html